# How to add charlie node to local relay-chain?

Tags: polkadot, parachain, relay-chain, rococo-local

Iam having two files

[rococo_custom_2_plain.json](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-docs/blob/main/static/assets/tutorials/cumulus/chain-specs/rococo-custom-2-plain.json)
[image]

1. What does beefy means?
2. What s the difference b/w alice vs alice_stash & bob vs bob-stash ?
3. From the above image how can i able to step up for new node ie., charlie?

[rococo_local_plain_200.json]
(https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sks5s8BEouuxwFMV9zAkqjkNWr27Uc00/view?usp=sharing)

how can i add charlie node as collator same as alice & bob.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

BEEFY (Bridge Efficiency Enabling Finality Yielder) is a secondary protocol running alongside GRANDPA to support efficient bridging with non-Substrate blockchains.

- https://github.com/paritytech/grandpa-bridge-gadget

Video on BEEFY:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZmIa_4hPRZ8

What is the difference between Alice vs Alice Stash?

Both are predefined dev accounts:

```
$ ./target/release/node-template key inspect //Alice
Secret Key URI `//Alice` is account:
  Network ID:        substrate 
 Secret seed:       0xe5be9a5092b81bca64be81d212e7f2f9eba183bb7a90954f7b76361f6edb5c0a
  Public key (hex):  0xd43593c715fdd31c61141abd04a99fd6822c8558854ccde39a5684e7a56da27d
  Account ID:        0xd43593c715fdd31c61141abd04a99fd6822c8558854ccde39a5684e7a56da27d
  Public key (SS58): 5GrwvaEF5zXb26Fz9rcQpDWS57CtERHpNehXCPcNoHGKutQY
  SS58 Address:      5GrwvaEF5zXb26Fz9rcQpDWS57CtERHpNehXCPcNoHGKutQY
$ ./target/release/node-template key inspect //Alice//stash
Secret Key URI `//Alice//stash` is account:
  Network ID:        substrate 
 Secret seed:       0x3c881bc4d45926680c64a7f9315eeda3dd287f8d598f3653d7c107799c5422b3
  Public key (hex):  0xbe5ddb1579b72e84524fc29e78609e3caf42e85aa118ebfe0b0ad404b5bdd25f
  Account ID:        0xbe5ddb1579b72e84524fc29e78609e3caf42e85aa118ebfe0b0ad404b5bdd25f
  Public key (SS58): 5GNJqTPyNqANBkUVMN1LPPrxXnFouWXoe2wNSmmEoLctxiZY
  SS58 Address:      5GNJqTPyNqANBkUVMN1LPPrxXnFouWXoe2wNSmmEoLctxiZY
```

In the [node-template](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/) Alice's key is normally used as the sudo key:

- https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/blob/6a8b2b12371395979099d2c79ccc1860531b0449/node/src/chain_spec.rs#L54

Take a look at this tutorial on how to add additional nodes:

- https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/get-started/trusted-network